# shape file, prisecroads, abutting two states

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, esri

Using R, and two shape files: tl_2015_01_prisecroads (alabama) and tl_2015_13_prisecroads georgia), read as two R objects using readOGR(). I need to focus on an area that includes both West Georgia and East Alabama. I tried both rbind() and spRbind() to no avail.

```
ga_al <- rbind(alabama, georgia, fix.duplicated.IDs=TRUE)
  Error in as(x, "SpatialLines") : 
  no method or default for coercing “logical” to “SpatialLines”

ga_al <- spRbind(alabama, georgia)
  Error in spRbind(as(obj, "SpatialLines"), as(x, "SpatialLines")) : 
  non-unique line IDs
```

Question 1: How to I combine two shape files to map an area in both states?
Question 2: How would I go about zooming in on a smaller area of the combined shape files?

Comment: Post links to the two files.

Comment: base graphics? ggplot2? which plotting system?

Comment: So, CC, did either of the answers fit your question?

Answer (score 5):

```
library(tigris)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
```

The `tigris` pkg is a better interface to TIGER data. `devtools::install_github("walkerke/tigris")`.

```
alabama <- primary_secondary_roads("alabama")
georgia <- primary_secondary_roads("georgia")
```

Base plots can combine both together without doing `rbind`ing:

```
plot(alabama)
plot(georgia, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

ggplot2 plots can also:

```
# this takes a little while if doing both primary & secondary roads
alabama_dat <- fortify(alabama)
georgia_dat <- fortify(georgia)

# so does this
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=alabama_dat, map=alabama_dat,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="black", fill="white", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=georgia_dat, map=georgia_dat,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="black", fill="white", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

You can use `xlim` and `ylim` in ggplot to "zoom" in.

Comment: Thank you. Every now and then, I see responses that are gold medal responses, and this is one of them. If you were local, I'd buy you a beer or three.

Answer (score 3):

It seemed like your question  was specifically about combining the shapefiles, so let me try to answer that.

In order for `spRbind(...)` to succeed several conditions must be met:

1. None of the line ID's can be duplicated. This is a problem because both shapefiles start their numbering at ID="0".
2. Both attribute tables must have exactly the same columns/column names. This is not a problem here.
3. The row names in each attribute table must correspond to the line IDs
4. The coordinate reference systems must be the same. In practice this means that the proj4strings for both shapefiles must be *identical*. You would think that this would not be a problem, but no... It turns out that while the projections are indeed the same (long/lat), the P4S are slightly different.

So we have to fix all this before we can use `spRbind(...)`, as follows:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)   # for spRbind(...)

nAL <- length(alabama@lines)
nGA <- length(georgia@lines)
for (i in 1:nGA) georgia@lines[[i]]@ID=as.character(nAL+i-1)
rownames(georgia@data) <- 1:nGA + nAL-1
proj4string(alabama) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs")
proj4string(georgia) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs")
georgia@data$state <- "GA"
alabama@data$state <- "AL"
both <- spRbind(georgia,alabama)
```

This code uses the shapefiles from the other answer. First we modify the line ID's for GA to start where the IDs for AL end (e.g. no duplicates), then we set the attribute table rownames appropriately, then we set the P4S for both to the same thing. Finally, we add a column to the attribute tables for the two states indicating the state (not necessary for `spRbind(...)` but useful later).

So `both` contains the spatial lines for both states, and an attribute table that combines both states' attribute tables. Now we can plot this is several ways (some examples follow):

```
plot(both, col=ifelse(both@data$state=="GA","red","green"))
```

[image]

Using ggplot with a file this large is very slow, but IMO the extra flexibility makes up for that. So first we use `fortify(...)` to convert `both` to a format suitable for use with ggplot, then merge that on the `id` field with the attributes table.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)   # data.table join is much faster than merge(...)
gg.dt <- setkey(setDT(fortify(both)), id)
gg.dt <- gg.dt[setDT(cbind(id=rownames(both@data),both@data))]
```

Now we can make the plots:

```
# plot all roads, color coded by state
ggplot(gg.dt, aes(x=long, y=lat)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group=group, color=state)) +
  theme_bw() + coord_map()
```

[image]

```
# plot all roads, color coded by type of road
ggplot(gg.dt, aes(x=long, y=lat)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group=group, color=RTTYP)) +
  theme_bw() + coord_map()
```

[image]

```
# plot only interstates, color by state
ggplot(gg.dt[gg.dt$RTTYP=="I",], aes(x=long, y=lat)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group=group, color=state)) +
  theme_bw() + coord_map()
```

[image]

```
# zoom into area surrounding Atlanta
library(ggmap)              # for geocode(...)
ATL <- geocode("atlanta")   # centriod for Atlante, GA
ggplot(gg.dt[gg.dt$RTTYP=="I",], aes(x=long, y=lat)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group=group, color=state)) +
  theme_bw() + coord_map()+
  geom_point(data=ATL, aes(x=lon, y=lat), color="red", size=4)+
  with(ATL,xlim(lon-1,lon+1))+with(ATL,ylim(lat-1,lat+1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your response is also a gold medal response. Is it something in the water of ggplot2 guys? I really appreciate your time and effort and (again) if you were local I'd buy you a beer or three.